# Inheritance in Knockout.js ViewModels

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, prototypal-inheritance

I have a rowNumber property in each of my 5 view Models. Also, there is a computed observable based on the rowNumber property. Here is the code:

```
function EntityViewModel() {
    this.rowNumber = ko.observable();

    this.isOdd = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.rowNumber() % 2 != 0;
    }, this);

    this.isEven = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.rowNumber() % 2 == 0;
    }, this);
}
```

I have a CountryViewModel which inherits from EntityViewModel as follows:

```
CountryViewModel.prototype = new EntityViewModel();

function CountryViewModel() {
    this.id = ko.observable();
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.abbrev = ko.observable();
}
```

Questions:
Can I now set the rowNumber from CountryViewModel object as follows:

```
var cvm = new CountryViewModel();
cvm.rowNumber(index);
```

In my case, the computed observable isOdd / isEven is not getting computed properly. It appears that the rowNumber is 0, though I setting rowNumbers through CountryViewModel. Is there any problem with the computed observable function - especially the context being set to this?

Comment: Seems to be working **[fine over here](http://jsfiddle.net/FERxr/)**. Could you provide us with a JSFiddle with more details about the problem?

Comment: Well, requires knockout.js, so JSFiddle may not work. I found out that all the Country View models have the value of 20 (which is the last rowNumber) Crazy, but not sure how to fix it?

Comment: My JSfiddle also includes Knockout.js - you can add resouces (JS and CSS) in the "Manage Resources" tab on the left side. Please make a working example with your problem there.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I have attached the jFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vijayst/Ht8GR/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the prototype you can do something like the following:

```
function EntityViewModel() {
    // ...
}
function CountryViewModel() {
    EntityViewModel.apply(this);
}
```

I've updated your jsfiddle as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ht8GR/4/